# Is there a way to sync two sqlite3 databases?

Tags: database, sqlite, replication

I'm leaning toward using CouchDB, but short of that is there a way to sync two sqlite3 databases that have the same schema? I can try to use UID primary keys instead of auto-incremented ones, but I don't know the next steps if there are any.

Answer (score 0):

http://old.nabble.com/Attempting-to-merge-large-databases-td18131366.html

that or RSync should get what you need.

Comment: Rsync, really? How does that handle conflicts between two sqlite3 databases?

Comment: @dan: It doesn't. In fact rsync would completely replace target database with the source database.